# Cmdlet: Have user enter complex data-types on powershell automatic prompting

Tags: c#, powershell, user-interface, types

I want to have my user enter data for my custom made data-type 'MyExampleType'.

pseudo-code:

```
 [Cmdlet("Set", "MyExampleData")]
    public class SetMyExampleData
    {
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true)]
        public MyExampleType ExampleData { get; set; }
```

As far as I understand it, on automatic prompting, powershell expects the user to pass an instance of MyExampleType when asked for 'ExampleData'.

Is it somehow possible to make powershell ask for any value on its own? So, if 'MyExampleType' would look like this:

```
public class MyExampleType
{
   public string Key { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
```

That powershell then would ask for 'Key', and then for 'Value'?

I've generally trouble creating commandlets to provide basic configuration of a larger bit of software (in terms of adding sets of configuration data to it) and don't know a way yet to have the user enter data thats a bit more complex than just single values. Mabye I'm on the wrong way here generally...

Answer (score 0):

You could write an intermediate function with all fields as parameters which will assign these parameters to your custom type object properties and then call this function without any parameter. In this case powershell will ask to enter every parameter's value. Example (assuming $obj is defined somewhere else):

```
function fillMyType
{
   param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Key,
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Value
   )

   $obj.Key=$Key
   $obj.Value=$Value
}

fillMyType
```